# Change font color of whole matrix including the brackets of matrix

Tags: equations, color, matrices

I want to change the font color of complete matrix including the matrix braces to red color. The MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{Ex5eq2}
M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 0& 0 \\ 0 &0 &1 &0 \\0& 0&0 &1\\ -2K & K_i &  K_p  - 5 & K_d 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

How can I change the font color of the complete matrix (including square brackets [])to red ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `\color` you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{Ex5eq2}
M = {\color{red}\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 0& 0 \\ 0 &0 &1 &0 \\0& 0&0 &1\\ -2K & K_i &  K_p  - 5 & K_d 
\end{bmatrix}}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```